# addthis make magento bundle product error

Tags: javascript, magento, addthis

I got a problem about magento bundle products here. The price won't get updated everytime I make come options change on the products. And I also can't add it to the cart. I've spent several days to find the problem and finally I realize that the problem comes from this addthis snippet that I insert

```
<!-- AddThis Button BEGIN -->
<div class="addthis_toolbox addthis_default_style ">
<a class="addthis_button_facebook_like" fb:like:layout="button_count"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
<a class="addthis_button_google_plusone" g:plusone:size="medium"></a>
<a class="addthis_counter addthis_pill_style"></a>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://s7.addthis.com/js/250/addthis_widget.js#pubid=xa-4e770a31017c7f26"></script>
<!-- AddThis Button END -->
```

I put that addthis snippet on my `default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml` files. I guess it might caused by some conflict between magento's default theme script with the script from addthis.

Can anyone help me on this?? or maybe give me a better alternatives other than addthis

thank you very much :)

Comment: Do you see any errors in Firebug console?

Comment: Google +1 - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/Yireo/extension/6963/yireo_googleplusone

Comment: Facebook Like - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/TemplatesMaster/extension/3816/facebooklb

Comment: Twitter - http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/C3+Media/extension/4446/c3_tweetbutton

Comment: I use all of these with success.  The nice thing is that they all have adminhtml configuration, all are free, and they have xml layouts so that you can position them anywhere.

Comment: I will recommend this paid extension however, http://ecommerce.aheadworks.com/magento-extensions/facebook-link.html

Comment: @WebFlakeStudio: no, I don't see any error in firebug

Comment: @Mustafa does your site has public access? I want to see your bundle product page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had same problem! Try replacing

```
<a class="addthis_button_tweet"></a>
```

with:

IFRAME snippet available from https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tweet-button
That should work! :)

Comment: thanks... I notice that the problem comes from twitter's javascript. There's a function there named bundle which collide with magento's prototype script on bundled product

Answer (score 3):

I have always been a 'seeder' of stockoverflow, get the information i need then bolt. But i thought id share this little tid bit.

Simple tweak i found it in a slightly different place.

"app/design/frontend/default/MYTHEME/template/***ajax***/catalog/product/view.phtml"

i just commented out `<a class="addthis_button_tweet></a>` from there and BOOM.

you have no idea the lengths i went to before finding this. Thanks

For people looking to solve this problem, i tried just about everything i could find, modifying option.phtml, effects.js, scpoptions.phtml, produt.js etc... and all along it was twitter